# Kafka KStream-KStream windowed Join explanation

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using

> KStream.join(KStream other, ValueJoiner 
>   joiner, JoinWindows)

let's take this example:

Stream 1-------------------Stream 2

key | Value-----------------key | Value

1 | A------------------------1 | A

---

2 | B -----------------------2 | B

---

3 | C -----------------------3 | C

---

1 | D------------------------4 | D

---

1 | E------------------------2 | E

what is the result of this stream making a KStream 1 join KStream 2

Comment: Depends on your window size... Check out this blog post, that explains joins in Kafka Streams in detail: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Comment: lets say all are in the same window

Answer (score 2):

It all records fall into the sliding window you would get

1 (A-A), 2 (B-B), 3 (C-C), 1 (D-A), 1 (E-A), 2 (B-E)

The blog post mentions explains it: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/